# Fubini-Tonelli for signed measures

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I know that there is a Fubini-Tonelli Theorem for complex measures, but, in the version that I have seen, both measures must have finite total variation. I would be interested in a generalization to signed measures where the variation is allowed to be infinite. For what I would like to prove the following restrictions would be acceptable: i) one of the measures can be a positive measure, in fact, the Lebesgue measure ii) the other measure is a signed measure that can take the value $+\infty$ but not $-\infty$. Is there a Fubini-Tonelli Theorem for this situation? References welcome.